# Form submission special behavior

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that contains a "search" text input and a button.

When the user submits the form (using the button or the enter key) he is redirected to a specific page followed by the value he entered in the text field.

how could I achieve that?

**I need a solution that runs correctly in different browsers !**

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to define the method as GET and the action as the URL in the form tag?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Yea I'm slow tonight:

```
<form method="GET" location="myNewPage.aspx" >
</form>
```

Add an onsubmit that calls a javascript function to your form tag and then in that function do a window.location to the page you want with the value of the textbox.

```
<script type="javascript">

function postData() {
     var myVal = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
     window.location = "myNewPage.aspx?search=" + myVal;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="javascript:postData();">
<input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchbox" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does not work correctly.. the form is still do traditional 'get' behavior

Comment: Don't put the method tag in the form then?

Comment: pass the event to the function and use .preventDefault()

Comment: @Avitus that's what i did exactly

Comment: @meo Can you explain with an example

Comment: just add `return false` at the end of the postData function.